# I have an old Apple II computer,but cannot find any info on model # A2M001

Tags: apple-ii, identify-this-computer

My father had an old Apple II and I'm trying to find some info on it. Any help would be appreciated The model # is A2M001 and the disk drives are also A2M003-62498. I have seen other models but None with M in them.

Comment: If you could add some photos of the computer's case, motherboard, and the labels you are referring to, then there are many people here who can help provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6):

A2M001 is for one printed on the power supply and therefore only a rough identification. It may be a II, as well as an early II+. Similarly, A2M003 is the type number for next to all Disk II drives.

For a real identification things like the keyboard (power cap), board revision and board serial number might be helpful.